# Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) error while parsing XML using XML::LibXML

Tags: perl, parsing, utf-8, xml-libxml

I am parsing XML files using XML::LibXML. For the following XML entry I get the error:

```
Malformed UTF-8 character (fatal) at C:/Perl64/site/lib/XML/LibXML/Error.pm line 217
```

which is

```
$context=~s/[^\t]/ /g;
```

The entry in XML is the following

```
<MedlineCitation Owner="NLM" Status="MEDLINE">
<PMID Version="1">15177811</PMID>
<DateCreated>
<Year>2004</Year>
<Month>06</Month>
<Day>04</Day>
</DateCreated>
<DateCompleted>
<Year>2004</Year>
<Month>08</Month>
<Day>11</Day>
</DateCompleted>
<DateRevised>
<Year>2011</Year>
<Month>04</Month>
<Day>07</Day>
</DateRevised>
<Article PubModel="Print">
<Journal>
<ISSN IssnType="Print">0278-2626</ISSN>
<JournalIssue CitedMedium="Print">
<Volume>55</Volume>
<Issue>2</Issue>
<PubDate>
<Year>2004</Year>
<Month>Jul</Month>
</PubDate>
</JournalIssue>
<Title>Brain and cognition</Title>
<ISOAbbreviation>Brain Cogn</ISOAbbreviation>
</Journal>
<ArticleTitle>Efficiency of orientation channels in the striate cortex for distributed categorization process.</ArticleTitle>
<Pagination>
<MedlinePgn>352-4</MedlinePgn>
</Pagination>
<Affiliation>Cognitive Science Department, Université de Liège, Belgium. mmermillod@ulg.ac.be</Affiliation>
<AuthorList CompleteYN="Y">
<Author ValidYN="Y">
<LastName>Mermillod</LastName>
<ForeName>Martial</ForeName>
<Initials>M</Initials>
</Author>
<Author ValidYN="Y">
<LastName>Chauvin</LastName>
<ForeName>Alan</ForeName>
<Initials>A</Initials>
</Author>
<Author ValidYN="Y">
<LastName>Guyader</LastName>
<ForeName>Nathalie</ForeName>
<Initials>N</Initials>
</Author>
</AuthorList>
<Language>eng</Language>
<PublicationTypeList>
<PublicationType>Journal Article</PublicationType>
</PublicationTypeList>
</Article>
<MedlineJournalInfo>
<Country>United States</Country>
<MedlineTA>Brain Cogn</MedlineTA>
<NlmUniqueID>8218014</NlmUniqueID>
<ISSNLinking>0278-2626</ISSNLinking>
</MedlineJournalInfo>
<CitationSubset>IM</CitationSubset>
<CommentsCorrectionsList>
<CommentsCorrections RefType="ErratumIn">
<RefSource>Brain Cogn. 2005 Jul;58(2):245</RefSource>
</CommentsCorrections>
<CommentsCorrections RefType="RepublishedIn">
<RefSource>Brain Cogn. 2005 Jul;58(2):246-8</RefSource>
<PMID Version="1">16044513</PMID>
</CommentsCorrections>
</CommentsCorrectionsList>
<MeshHeadingList>
<MeshHeading>
<DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="Y">Neural Networks (Computer)</DescriptorName>
</MeshHeading>
<MeshHeading>
<DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Neurons</DescriptorName>
<QualifierName MajorTopicYN="N">physiology</QualifierName>
</MeshHeading>
<MeshHeading>
<DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Orientation</DescriptorName>
<QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">physiology</QualifierName>
</MeshHeading>
<MeshHeading>
<DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Pattern Recognition, Visual</DescriptorName>
<QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">physiology</QualifierName>
</MeshHeading>
<MeshHeading>
<DescriptorName MajorTopicYN="N">Visual Cortex</DescriptorName>
<QualifierName MajorTopicYN="Y">physiology</QualifierName>
</MeshHeading>
</MeshHeadingList>
</MedlineCitation>
```

But the things I want out of this entry is PMID, DateRevised, PubDate, ArticleTitle, CommentsCorrectionList, and MeshHeadingList. But, if I remove Affiliation which contains some other character this error is no more. How should I fix this error?

Comment: Is your file actually saved in UTF-8?  I suspect it's not, but that LibXML thinks it is, and is getting mad when it hits the "Université de Liège" bit.

Comment: @XavierHolt due you mean the line "<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>" at the start of the file? If yes, it has this line. I am sorry if this is a silly question, I am not of this field.

Comment: That's half of it.  That part tells your XML parser what character encoding to expect.  The other half is what encoding you saved your file to disk in.  For example, if you saved your file in UTF-8, the `é` character would be represented by the byte sequence `0xC3A9`, but if you saved your file in Windows-1252, it would be represented by the single byte `0xE9`.  And if LibXML is expecting UTF-8 characters, but hits something that isn't UTF-8, it'll throw an error.

Comment: And now the useful bit - most modern text editors will give you the option to specify a particular character encoding.  That'll be the first thing you want to try - make sure your file is actually saved in UTF-8, like you tell LibXML it is in the `<?xml ?>` line.  Cheers!

Comment: This really helps. It worked. This is fine as I did it in text editor. Another major concern is I have about huge XML data and they are sitting on my Lab's server. What about them? How do I convert them into UTF-8. I got them in zip files and then I unzipped then. Is there anyway to do it while unzipping on server? I got this link http://docs.moodle.org/20/en/Converting_files_to_UTF-8 that says about converting the files in UNIX. Should I follow this or do you suggest any other way to do it?

Comment: You don't need to convert the file, you just need to use the right header: `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp1252"?>`

Comment: I second ikegami's comment.  Seems odd that your files would have been saved with an incorrect encoding given, but hey...  Anyway, good luck!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could either convert the file to the specified encoding (UTF-8), or you can specify the encoding actually used for the file. (`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="cp1252"?>`).

Notepad can be used to convert to UTF-8, and so can Perl:

```
perl -pe"
   BEGIN {
      binmode STDIN,  ':encoding(cp1252)';
      binmode STDOUT, ':encoding(UTF-8)';
   }
" < file.cp1252 > file.UTF-8
```

(You'll have to remove the line breaks I've added for readability.)

Comment: [piconv](http://p3rl.org/piconv) ships with Perl. `piconv -f cp1252 -t UTF-8 < file.cp1252 > file.UTF-8`

Comment: @daxim, Cool, nI had never heard of it.